# Modify x-axis position

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When you use `plot` function in Matlab, you are presented with y and x axis on the left and at the bottom respectively. But I'd like the x-axis to strike through in the middle of the figure with the scales and numbers like so:

[image]

I beg a pardon for my amateur paint skills. But basically I want the x-axis to move to the top for example and I want to have numbers there and those small bumps like indicated on the red line but all the way through to the right, but I do not want a number under each "bump" just the whole numbers. I tried to google the answer but couldn't find anything.

Clearly, I do not want two x-axis, so ideally the one at the bottom would be gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, apart from some ugly hackish solutions (can be found on [FEX](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)), the functionality you want is not applicable in Matlab. And it doesn't seem so, that it changed with the recent update. So if you *really* need that, save your figure as vector graphic and edit it with Inkscape or Illustrator, or just draw it with Latex/pgfplots/Matlab2Tikz from the beginning.

However the 2014b update of the graphics engine introduced the following solution using some [**undocumented features**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-part-2). Maybe this is already sufficient, I dare to say it's the closest you can get without coding handstands.

*Matlab R2014b or higher is required!*

```
%// example
t = linspace(0,4*pi);
plot(t,sin(t))
ylim([-1.5,1.5]); xlim([0,4*pi]);

%// get handle
h = gca;

%// modify y-axis
h.YBaseline.BaseValue = 0.5;
h.YBaseline.Visible = 'on'; 
h.XRuler.Axle.Visible = 'off';

%// modify x-axis
h.XBaseline.BaseValue = 2;
h.XBaseline.Visible = 'on';
h.YRuler.Axle.Visible = 'off';
```

[image]

Comment: pretty good :) This is what one of my friends found: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10473-plotaxisatorigin

Answer (score 0):

that's a bit trickier than expected because matlab doesn't provide this feature.
You could just do it manually by drawing lines and switching off the original axes.

I found some example on the [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/26095)

```
t=linspace(0,10,100);plot(t,sin(2*pi*t));
axis([-10 10 -1 1]);

y=get(gca,'ytick');
x=get(gca,'xtick');
hold on
Lx=line([x(1) x(11)],[0 0]);
Ly=line([0 0],[y(1) y(11)]);
set(Lx,'color',[1 0 0]);
set(Ly,'color',[1 0 0]);
for i=1:length(x)
    plot(x(i),0,'k*',0,y(i),'k*');
    text(x(i),-.05,num2str(x(i)));
    text(-1,y(i),num2str(y(i)));
end
set(gca,'yticklabel',[],'xticklabel',[],'ytick',[],'xtick',[]);
set(gca,'visible','off')
```

[image: matlab figure]

but you should also check on [fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) as there is probably some better solution already around.