# How to shift the bottom xy plane to origin level in a 3d plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, axes

I'm plotting a 3d surface in MATLAB with `surf` and the result is like this:

[image]

How can I shift the position of the xy-plane at the bottom to the position marked with red square (along with the labels)?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33708402/2605073) for the 3D-case: means it probably can't be done with Matlab. Only way would be to draw the whole plane by yourself, good luck!

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Unfortunately from 2D to 3D is exactly where the problem is. Using gca we can adjust the position of the baselines of x-axis and y-axis but not z-axis because the gca object does not have the method for z-axis baseline.